# getting username from siteminder sso

Tags: java, siteminder

My Application requires a Siteminder SSO login. I am able to capture the SM_USER which is the Employee Id  by

```
request.getHeader("SM_USER");
```

Now I want to capture the Employee Name which is stored in Cookie. 
I used `request.getHeader("Cookie");`
The cookie which I am getting is like

```
lcid=1033; IDEALDOMAIN=53AvKXzgyShYOE5+I4sX4Q==; SUPERUSER=False; ADIDMAPPINGFLAG=7LQlj8/2nvgLQlH4X/M4Gw==; INITMAPPINGSTATE=True; LDAPVALIDATIONFLAG=53AvKXzgyShYOE5+I4sX4Q==; SSOCONTENTNAME=IXK93MPqLZSIGwzx7YZ31XI8LtsJuLAActhQvcJy7sw=; SSOCONTENTEMAIL=Pym0Td3ayVI/gasQDYx0GJGt78jalJIJGLlFLVGsod8=; EID=AljFH+Zu6YpIYtFVw7TEZw==; IDMPROVISIONED=True; AD=Uyv5wIQS5rx76pd0hBocfg==; ACTIVEVIEW=vopKOOSRtqVJg2cbvwFkYg==; AMP_Session={"**username**":"**xxxxxxxx xxxxx**","opened": true}; JSESSIONID=0000DW8l91J8oZilIKjHYvb_Ahi:19t5pcqiq; SMSESSION=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
```

Now How can I get the username from this Cookie

Answer (score 1):

Just like you are using request.getHeader("SM_USER") to obtain the userid, the usual suggestion in the Siteminder world is to use the so-called Response for Siteminder to help you retrieve whatever user attributes you need, in the case the Employee Name, and make them available in the Header for you. In short, you would need to ask your Siteminder administrator to configure this for you.

Since Cookie lives on a Browser, so unless the Cookie is encrypted, the user on the Browser would be able to tamper it and render the Cookie useless. If a Cooke is encrypted, then your program would need to know how to decrypt it and hence you would have a far more challenging task to do.